# Get-IISAppPool | Select-Object State is empty in .NET

Tags: .net, powershell

I want to get the status of the application pool from IIS with .net

I am using the following powershell command : `Get-IISAppPool | Select-Object State`

```
[Route("api/getstates")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetStates()
    {
        string commandGetState = "Get-IISAppPool | Select-Object State";
        HttpResponseMessage request;
        try
        {
            var stat = ExecuteCommandDefault(commandGetState);
            request = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, stat);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, exception.Message);
        }
        return request;
    }

 private string ExecuteCommandDefault(string command)
    {
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();
        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript(command);
        pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
        Collection<PSObject> result = pipeline.Invoke();
        runspace.Close();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (PSObject psObject in result)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(psObject.ToString());
        }
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

The result i'm getting when running this statement in my .net framework application is this:

```
"\r\nState\r\n-----\r\n     \r\n     \r\n     \r\n     \r\n     \r\n\r\n\r\n"
```

I get state followed by a line and 5 empty new lines.

When i run the following code with the command to get all the names so : `Get-IISAppPool | Select-Object Name` I get 5 application pools

```
"\r\nName                   \r\n----                   \r\nClr4IntegratedAppPool  \r\nClr4ClassicAppPool     \r\nClr2IntegratedAppPool  \r\nClr2ClassicAppPool     \r\nUnmanagedClassicAppPool\r\n\r\n\r\n"
```

So I think it is actually looping over them but it just can't see the value.

When I run both commands in powershell they both work fine.

So does anyone knows why I can't see the state when i'm running the command to get the states in a .NET project?